# How to give motion(animation) to the FBX files using Python?

Tags: python, motion, mediapipe, fbx, ply

I am having multiple FBX file's for each frame of a video near about 1000 of FBX files. I want to play or make animation using those all FBX files.

I tried every possible way to do the same but not working properly.

Basically, I am having 468 3d landmarks in FBX file which are obtained by using mediapipe face mesh.

I tried with blender and autodesk but it's also not giving me a proper result.

Thanks in advance!

I need to make a motion of through these FBX files.

All I want to do using Python.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.